# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop problem with gnome; unity works fine

Tags: unity, gnome, upgrade, login

I just upgraded to 18.04 from 16.04. The upgrade went through with no error messages, but I hit the login loop right after the upgrade: at the login page, after typing the correct password, the screen goes black for 1-2 seconds and then goes back to the original login page. I have tried various suggestions found online (including this forum). An incomplete list of items  I tried are:

- Removed and reinstalled the latest Nvidia driver
- Removed `~/.local` folder
- checked all customized entries in `~/.profile`
- removed the `~/.Xauthority` file
- checked that my account has the ownership of the `~/.ICEauthority`
- switched between GDM3 and LightDM (the symptom is the same between different display managers)

There are probably a few other things I tried that I cannot recall anymore. Finally, I found that through LightDM I have three desktop environments to choose from:

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu on wayland
- Unity (default)

By default, the system directs me to the first option "Ubuntu" (which I assume is the new Gnome environment?). If I switch to unity, the desktop does load with no issues. Wayland has the same login loop problem.

Up to this point, I am running out of options. I am now sticking with unity and not sure if this is a good long-term solution. Any thoughts on why GNOME does not launch?

The machine is an "Asus N56JR" laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. Try the following from the working Unity environment

1. Using the **Ubuntu Software Application** install **GNOME Tweaks**
2. **GNOME Tweaks** has a menu item named ***Startup Applications***
3. Remove all or only the application that is likely to be causing an issue. In my case the application was System Load Indicator
4. Logout of the Unity environment and try to login to the default Ubuntu environment.